# RestSharp Authentication on Net 6? Works in Framework and curl

Tags: .net-6.0, restsharp

I'm having an issue with rest sharp authentication a request. I moved the business logic into a .Net Standard DLL. RestSharp version 106.15.0.

When I run the same code in .Net Framework 4.6.1 it works. No matter what i try in .Net 6 it seems to fail unauthorized. I've tried updating Rest Sharp to the latest version of restsharp 108 and using the new OAuth authenticators but it still comes back unauthorized. I get get the initial bearer token but the subsequent API calls fail.

Really stumped.

Here is the creation of the Client

```
public EmployeeApi(Uri basePath, string userName, string password)
{
    restClient = new RestClient(basePath);
    restClient.Authenticator = new Authenticator(basePath, userName, password);
    restClient.FollowRedirects = true;
}
```

The Authenticator

```
internal class Authenticator : IAuthenticator
{
    private readonly CredentialCache credentials = new CredentialCache();

    public Authenticator(Uri loginServerUrl, string username, string password)
    {
        if (loginServerUrl == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("loginServerUrl");
        }

        registerAuthenticationModule(loginServerUrl);
        credentials.Add(loginServerUrl, "DayforceAuthentication", new NetworkCredential(username, password, loginServerUrl.Host));
    }

    private static AuthenticationModule registerAuthenticationModule(Uri loginServerUrl)
    {
        IEnumerator registeredModules = AuthenticationManager.RegisteredModules;
        AuthenticationModule authenticationModule;
        while (registeredModules.MoveNext())
        {
            object current = registeredModules.Current;
            if (current is AuthenticationModule)
            {
                authenticationModule = (AuthenticationModule)current;
                if (authenticationModule.LoginServerUrl.Equals(loginServerUrl))
                {
                    return authenticationModule;
                }
            }
        }

        authenticationModule = new AuthenticationModule(loginServerUrl);
        AuthenticationManager.Register(authenticationModule);
        return authenticationModule;
    }

    public void Authenticate(IRestClient client, IRestRequest request)
    {
        request.Credentials = credentials;
    }
}
```

The AuthenicationModule

```
internal class AuthenticationModule : IAuthenticationModule
{
    internal const string DAYFORCE_AUTHENTICATION = "DayforceAuthentication";

    private readonly CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache();

    private readonly Uri loginServerUrl;

    internal CredentialCache CredentialCache => credentialCache;

    internal Uri LoginServerUrl => loginServerUrl;

    public string AuthenticationType => "DayforceAuthentication";

    public bool CanPreAuthenticate => false;

    internal AuthenticationModule(Uri loginServerurl)
    {
        if (loginServerurl == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("loginServerurl");
        }

        loginServerUrl = loginServerurl;
    }

    public Authorization Authenticate(string challenge, WebRequest request, ICredentials credentials)
    {
        Authorization authorization = null;
        if (request == null || credentials == null)
        {
            authorization = null;
        }
        else
        {
            NetworkCredential credential = credentials.GetCredential(LoginServerUrl, "DayforceAuthentication");
            if (credential == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            string arg = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{credential.UserName}:{credential.Password}"));
            authorization = new Authorization($"Basic {arg}");
        }

        return authorization;
    }

    public Authorization PreAuthenticate(WebRequest request, ICredentials credentials)
    {
        return null;
    }


}
```

When i tried to rewrite it

```
internal class DayforceAuthenticator : AuthenticatorBase
{
    private readonly CredentialCache credentials = new CredentialCache();
    private readonly string _username;
    private readonly string _password;
    private readonly Uri _loginServUrl;


    public DayforceAuthenticator(Uri basepath, string username, string password) : base("")
    {
        _loginServUrl = new Uri(basepath);
        _username = username;
        _password = password;
    }




    protected override async ValueTask<Parameter> GetAuthenticationParameter(string accessToken)
    {
        Token = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Token) ? await GetToken() : Token;
        return new HeaderParameter(KnownHeaders.Authorization, Token);
    }

    protected async Task<string> GetToken()
    {
        var options = new RestClientOptions(_loginServUrl);
        using var client = new RestClient(options);

        var request = new RestRequest("connect/token")
            .AddParameter("grant_type", "password");

        request.AddParameter("Client_Id", "Dayforce.HCMAnywhere.Client");
        request.AddParameter("companyId", "Company1234");
        request.AddParameter("username", _username);
        request.AddParameter("password", _password);
        var response = await client.PostAsync<TokenResponse>(request);
        return $"{response!.token_type} {response!.access_token}";
    }

}
```

Not sure where to go from here. It may be a dependency issue with .Net 6 and .Net Framework 4.6.1 but i don't see what is missing. Any help would be appreciated.

i've tried updating the RestSharp Package and rewriting it.
I've tried using `client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(userName, password);`

Comment: The Credentials property is for NTLM credentials, I don't see how it can possibly work with OAuth tokens. Could you elaborate on that? How does the working curl request look like? Have you looked at the Twitter Authenticator sample in the docs?

Comment: Yes, the twitter sample was the template I used for the OAuth refactor.    So I believe the issue is the redirect. I’m .Net Framework the redirect follows correctly. In .Net Core it gets a different url and the redirect does not seem to follow. It then does the 401. Confused why the same code in a .net standard library works dofferent in Framework 4.6 and .Net 6

Comment: A .NET standard library doesn't really have any binary reference to the underlying platform API. It's the framework itself that translates all the calls. And they introduce breaking changes all the time. Like that MediaType being null worked in .NET 6 and suddenly started to crash in .NET 7...